# stack level too deep, run function before it WARNs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

WARN: stack level too deep 
Than i'm getting on my sidekiq console after few minutes. I have a background script for sidekiq and repeating it every 0.1 second. I am running only with 1 concurrency. But after it says "WARN: stack level too deep", the worker starts over again, and all my local variable data refresh. And it's bad.
Then i would like to run a script before "stack level too deep" warning. How to call a function before i get this warning?

I run sidekiq: `bundle exec sidekiq -c 1`

My sidekiq:

```
class HardWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  require 'sidekiq/api'
  sidekiq_options :retry => false

  def perform
    self.recalculate
  end

  def recalculate
    @number = 0
    def increment
      @number = @number+1
      sleep 0.1
      puts (@number)
      increment
    end
  end
end
```

My console log (incrementing)

```
882
883
884
2014-11-30T10:39:26.973Z 5071 TID-qoeag HardWorker JID-3279857b07c31ab4481db5e8 INFO: fail: 89.005 sec
2014-11-30T10:39:26.975Z 5071 TID-qoeag WARN: {"retry"=>true, "queue"=>"default", "class"=>"HardWorker", "args"=>[], "jid"=>"3279857b07c31ab4481db5e8", "enqueued_at"=>1417339371.1692605, "error_message"=>"stack level too deep", "error_class"=>"SystemStackError", "failed_at"=>1417342603.6595845, "retry_count"=>1, "retried_at"=>1417343966.9730375}
2014-11-30T10:39:26.975Z 5071 TID-qoeag WARN: stack level too deep
2014-11-30T10:39:26.975Z 5071 TID-qoeag WARN: /home/vartotojas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/sidekiq-3.2.6/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:110
2014-11-30T10:39:26.980Z 5071 TID-qoeag HardWorker JID-63fc10dfe81abb4fdb29a4a1 INFO: start
1
2
3
```

.. and i need it always to increment in background, but not in database.

If it's not possible to stop recalling the Worker, then i would like before the stack level too deep WARN, to save my last `@number` to Database.

How to make script before `"stack level too deep"` call?

Comment: No idea what's the underlying purpose of that?

Comment: The idea is to calculate x, y position(of monsters) in real time and when it reaches destination, recalculate destination and PUT to Redis all data, and with websockets give it to client. So i will have less PUT/GET. Every 0.1 second each monster moves towards destination 0.5 point, same in client-side and in sidekiq. Just when it reaches destination, sidekiq give to client new destination target for each monster.

Comment: Every 0.1 second i'm updating monsters_object[] variable with new data and if 8 seconds over, the data fetch from database again and start over. I need it to be always upgrading, no refresh

Comment: how do you call the `increment` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the deep recursion, the disadvantage of recursion is that you can get [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) exception (or just error). Your code have this:

```
def increment
  # ...
  increment
end
```

So since you have so called `tail recursion`, you are able with some labour expand it to a [loop](/questions/tagged/loop).In ruby wa it will look like:

```
FIXNUM_MAX = (2**(0.size * 8 -2) -1)
def increment
  (1..FIXNUM_MAX).each do |number|
     puts number
     sleep 0.1
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi. how to do this function every 0.1 second?

Comment: Thanks! It worked fine :) Dont know why i didnt think to do that :) Now it goes perfectly, never stops, doing 10k calculations, PUT/GET to redis  per second and never stop. Befor it was like 100/second and after some time anyway stops :)

Comment: Whit your correct answer i solved 4 weeks mission and can atleast keep going on more interesting things :) Atleast! Going to drink my first beer in last 2 months for the victory and get some happy rest :) I'm very thankful to you :)